# Subject RemoveMigrationStubs to Moderator/User Approval

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, moderator-tools, migrated-questions

I was not aware of this mechanism until today but discovered [it has been around for a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/212479), although the paper trail it leaves may be [much more recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/247647#247647).

I noticed it because a new user on RaspberryPi.SE asked, with regard to a question of his that had been closed as a duplicate, how he could delete his question because he felt that was the correct thing to do.

I started writing a comment explaining this was not necessary and that in fact it would be better to leave it, since questions closed as duplicates are helpful to other people searching the site with the same problem.  However, I then realized this would sound a bit foolish since [the duplicate question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/timeline/37732), which was migrated to U&L, had been deleted by Community because of "RemoveMigrationStubs" (I've since undeleted it).

I'm not sure how such a mechanism is appropriate in this, or many/most other cases.  The question was not migrated because it is a stupid question; I do not pass garbage on.  The question was migrated because this was an issue I had seen before and felt was better dealt with on U&L, possibly as a duplicate there (I did try to look for one myself first), and although that did not happen and in fact no useful answer seems to have been posted, I believe it is an issue that will re-occur.  In which case **the fact that somebody has already asked about it would be a useful thing to know**.

Instead, this record was effectively destroyed by the system. I'd propose that messages scheduled for deletion this way (and perhaps by some other similar mechanisms -- I don't have a problem with them categorically) should either be placed in a review queue ("Deletion queue") or else flagged for review first by a moderator.

On RaspberryPi.SE the number of migrated questions is small enough that this would not place any kind of burden on anybody, and I would guess the same is true proportionally most other places.

Another option would be to have the mechanism ignore upvoted migrated questions, which would provide an indirect means of preserving them, although I'd prefer the flagging solution.

## Migrated questions are akin to duplicate questions

...in that their status does not necessarily indicate the question was inappropriate in some fundamental sense (too broad, unclear, just plain bad), but that it was considered better off on a different SE site.  If the question remains with the migration link for posterity, then, as with duplicates, people searching for this issue later will have a chance of finding it.  Without that, they are more likely to waste their and other people's time by asking the question again.

Answer (score 10):

Migrated questions are completely different from duplicate questions in this regard. We delete migration stubs because you've inherently deemed that the question is **completely off-topic** for the current site, and users shouldn't expect to find an answer to it here.

Let's say the question *hadn't* been migrated, just closed as off-topic. Those are normally circumstances where the question should inevitably be deleted, because it doesn't belong on your site. If it *shouldn't* be deleted, then it probably shouldn't be closed as off-topic. The only difference in migrating it is that you're telling the user "hey, this doesn't belong here, but you could've asked it over there - let me transfer it for you."

If the question is worth keeping around on your site, then you probably shouldn't have migrated it. The migration tool itself is nested under the "off-topic" close reason, and it's not intended to be used for situations where the question is on-topic but could receive answers more quickly on another site. If you think they could, you can always just suggest the other site to them in a comment and let them decide where they want to ask it.

Also of note: undeleting the migration stub does nothing in the end. It will end up automatically deleted again whenever the script which looks for qualifying questions to delete runs again.

Comment: I think there is some very un-pragmatic ideology here.  The off-topicness of many of our questions relates to the fact that they are really general programming or linux oriented, and it is not in anyone's interest that we open the floor to unrestricted questions about python, etc., when these are better off on S.O.  It does not necessarily make such questions completely irrelevant. I realize this might imply revising some stone tablets, and will not be holding my breath...

Comment: Actually, it's useful to undelete migration stubs if the destination question is just about to get closed much after it was asked, to prevent certain answers from being deleted on both sites (due to the way migration rejection works).